Сколько... знают только
Сколько дополнительных расходов возникает во время ремонта из-за трещин в стенах знают только подрядчик и хозяин.
Нужен ли знак препинания перед "знают"?
Если да, то какой?

Нужна запятая, отделяющая придаточное от главного.
Главное: подрядчик и хозяин знают.
Знают что?
Сколько дополнительных расходов возникает во время ремонта из-за трещин в стенах.
Сколько дополнительных расходов возникает во время ремонта из-за трещин в стенах, знают только подрядчик и хозяин.
